# Infinity norm of the monic chebyshev polynomial

Tags: normed-spaces

Consider the monic Chebyshev polynomial $$\hat{C}_n(x) = 2^{1-n}\cos{(n\cos^{-1}{x})}.$$ Show that on the interval $[-1, 1]$, $$\left\|\hat{C}_n\right\|_\infty = 2^{1-n}.$$

---

$(1)$ Now I know we can do some manipulation firstly:

\begin{align}
\left\|\hat{C}_n\right\|_\infty &= \max_{x\in[-1,1]}\left|2^{1-n}\cos{(n\cos^{-1}{x})}\right| \\
&= 2^{1-n}\max_{x\in[-1,1]}\left|\cos{(n\cos^{-1}{x})}\right|
\end{align}

I know the max now present is 1 but I can't think of a formal justification for me to write that.

---

Show also, if $Q_n(x)$ is any other monic polynomial of degree $n$, that $$\left\|Q_n\right\|_\infty \ge \left\|\hat{C}_n\right\|_\infty = 2^{1-n}.$$

---

$(2)$ Suppose such a $Q_n$ exists, then we have that $$Q_n(x) = (x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n),$$ for some constants $a_1, ..., a_n$. Then the infinity norm is
\begin{align}
\|Q_n\|_\infty &= \max_{x\in[-1,1]}\left|(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)\right| \\
&\le \max_{x\in[-1,1]}|x-a_1|\cdots\max_{x\in[-1,1]}|x-a_n| \\
\end{align}

But I don't know how I'm ever going to get any cosines here to apply the result from $\|\hat{C}_n\|$.. Any times on question $(1)$ and $(2)$ would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), $|\cos(x)|\le 1$, with equality at, for example, $0$.